# Is there a rank for theories?

Tags: theory

I have been reading about many theories, some are more solid that the others.

I wonder if there is a way for non-professional to know the rank ( how trusted) this theory?

Example Strings Theory, i read that it is not proved yet and there is a good chance it could be wrong.

there are other theories like White Holes

How can I as non-professional know how trusted this theory without doing all the research?

Comment: Do you want to understand particular scientific areas without having formal training in them? That's really what popular science literature is for. There's no way of "ranking" different theories in different areas by how closely they fit the available facts - it's like comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there does not exist any ranking and you may be confused about some things.

1. A **theory** is a contemplative and rational type of abstract or generalizing thinking about a phenomenon, or the results of such thinking.
2. A **scientific theory** is an explanation of an aspect of the natural world that can be repeatedly tested and verified in accordance with the scientific method, using accepted protocols of observation, measurement, and evaluation of results. Where possible, theories are tested under controlled conditions in an experiment. In circumstances not amenable to experimental testing, theories are evaluated through principles of abductive reasoning. Established scientific theories have withstood rigorous scrutiny and embody scientific knowledge
3. **Scientific laws** are descriptive accounts of how nature will behave under certain conditions.
4. A **hypothesis**  is a *proposed* explanation for a phenomenon.

That is in broad.

To determine how *trusted* something is, it means it is widely accepted because it has been widely tested. If you want to know how 'trusty' something you read is, you can revise how many times it is cited, how widely is accepted, who are its detractors and why, how where there tests done, etc.

There is no easy magic ranking and I hope you see why. However, I think your question is important for the professionals to read and remember that some people might be very confused on some stuff as they have become quite distanced from the general vulgo/mases.

Answer (score 12):

No, there is no rank for theories.

Comment: And there should not be.

Comment: Actually, if you imagine theories to be similar to Bayesian constraints, and parameters modelled by priors, you could have various measures which indicate the statistical validity vs. modelling costs. In fact, this is what statistical learning/machine learning is much concerned about. So, if you are interested in how to rank "theories", that would be an approach to start with. It is not trivial to do that for fully developed, say, physics, theories, but it is not, strictly spoken, impossible. The main challenge would be how to cost the complexity of a "theory" appropriately.